# Bundle from DatePickerFragment to fragment nullpointer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm trying to pass some data from a datepickerfragment to the fragment from where is call but i get nullpointer when trying to get the data, heres my code of the datepicker

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    CreateFragment createFragment = new CreateFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("year",year);
    arguments.putInt("month",month);
    arguments.putInt("day",dayOfMonth);
    createFragment.setArguments(arguments);

    month = month+1;
    textviewDate = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textviewDate);
    textviewDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
}
```

and here is the code where i try to get the data:

```
public boolean checkDate(){

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    pickedYear = bundle.getInt("year");
    pickedMonth = bundle.getInt("month");
    pickedDay = bundle.getInt("day");
}
```

but i always gets me nullpointer, this is the error i get:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

by the way, the datepickerfragment is call from the same fragment, CreateFragment.
hope someone can help me out here.

this is the fragment:

```
public class CreateFragment extends Fragment {

//Codigo que envio al intent para saber que es mi request
private static final int PICK_CONTACT_CODE = 1;

private Button btnSearchContact,btnDateChange,btnTimeChange;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private EditText edittextPhoneNumber,edittextMessage;
private TextView textviewDate,textviewTime;
private int column,day,month,year,hour,minute,timeOfDay,pickedYear,pickedMonth,pickedDay;
private Calendar calendar;
private String contactPhoneNumber,currentDate,currentTime,morningOrAfternoon;
private View rootView;
private Realm realm;

public CreateFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Haciendo referencia a los componentes
    edittextPhoneNumber = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittextPhoneNumber);
    edittextMessage = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittextMessage);
    btnSearchContact = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonContacts);
    btnDateChange = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDateChange);
    btnTimeChange = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonTimeChange);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    textviewDate = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewDate);
    textviewTime = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewTime);

    //Referencia a la base de datos
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    //Llamando al metodo para poner la fecha en los textview
    setCurrentDate();

    textviewDate.setText(currentDate);
    textviewTime.setText(currentTime);

    //Llamando al fragment con el picker de fecha
    btnDateChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");

        }
    });

    //Llamando al fragment con el picker de hora
    btnTimeChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerDialog();
            timePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
        }
    });

    //Llamando a la app de contactos para elegir un numero
    btnSearchContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
            contactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(contactIntent,PICK_CONTACT_CODE);
        }
    });

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edittextPhoneNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_phone_empty,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (edittextMessage.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_message_empty,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(checkDate()){
                saveMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_message_saved,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                edittextPhoneNumber.getText().clear();
                edittextMessage.getText().clear();
                //Haciendo que el teclado se esconda
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            }
        }
    });
}
//Metodo para tomar la fecha actual y ponerla en los textview
public void setCurrentDate(){
    //Haciendo las instancias del calendar y tomando la fecha y hora actual
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //Le sumo 1 al mes porque inicia en 0
    month = month+ 1;
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timeOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    if (timeOfDay <= 0){
        morningOrAfternoon = "AM";
    }else {
        morningOrAfternoon = "PM";
    }

    currentDate = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
    //Calendar minute no agrega los ceros cuando es menos a 10 asi que hice un If
    if (minute <=9){
        currentTime = hour+":"+"0"+minute+" "+morningOrAfternoon;
    }else {
        currentTime = hour + ":" + minute + " " + morningOrAfternoon;
    }
}

//Confirmando que la fecha no sea menor a la actual
public boolean checkDate(){

    /*Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    pickedYear = bundle.getInt("year");
    pickedMonth = bundle.getInt("month");
    pickedDay = bundle.getInt("day");

    if (pickedYear < year){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_year_pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }else if (pickedMonth < month){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_month_pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }else if (pickedDay < day){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toast_day_pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }*/

    return true;
}
}
```

and this is the dialogfragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
private TextView textviewDate;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    /*CreateFragment createFragment = new CreateFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("year",year);
    arguments.putInt("month",month);
    arguments.putInt("day",dayOfMonth);
    createFragment.setArguments(arguments);*/

    month = month+1;
    textviewDate = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textviewDate);
    textviewDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the Fragment code. I guess your are calling check date before setArguments() is called

Comment: the checkdate() method is called when I press a button and the setArguments() is call when the user pick a date which is in the onDateSet method(posted above) of the fragmentDialog I have, so is called after the onDateset is done with the date.

Comment: please post the fragmet code

Comment: i just add the fragment and the dialogfragment just in case